# php string invisible character after get_file_contents()

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a .txt file generated from the management shell of an exchange server.

I am using php and want to use get_file_contents() to get the content of the file and then a preg_match() with "DisplayName". This problem applies to the whole file.

```
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");

//Does not work
preg_match("/DisplayName/", $file, $matches);

//Does work
preg_match("/D.i.s.p.l.a.y.N.a.m.e/", $file, $matches);

//Returns 1
preg_match("/D(.)i/", $file, $matches);
echo strlen($matches[1][0]);
```

How do I remove these invisible characters or what could it be?
Is there a function in php to find out what this character might be?

https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php says there are no hidden characters.

Example:

DisplayName        : Name

ServerName         : Server

PrimarySmtpAddress : Email

EmailAddresses     : {Email list}

I hope you guys are able to help me.

Comment: Copy/paste the text you have exactly here, into the question. Do not hesitate if you cannot see the chars.

Comment: hexdump -C should help, too for debugging.

Comment: Your `DisplayName` in the example has no special chars.

Comment: hexdump -C returned dots(.) between the characters... What is this? They are not visible when opening.

Comment: what is the hex value of the dots? Are they 0x00 nulls?

Comment: hexdump -C displays them as 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I was able to fix it like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$file = str_replace(chr(0), "", $file);
```

Comment: I would really advice against doing this. This may work out for the example text file for now, but you will get into trouble if the file should contains Unicode characters.  Just compair the [ASCII table](https://theasciicode.com.ar/) to the [Unicode table](https://unicode-table.com/en/) and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the file is encoded as Unicode where you expect it to be plain ASCII.

Try this:

```
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt", FILE_TEXT);
```

or a custom function:

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
     $content = file_get_contents($fn);
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}

$file = file_get_contents_utf8("file.txt");
```